# process a map containing boost::variant<int, double,long long> as value datatype

Tags: c++

I have a map data structure containing a string as key and multiple data type as values. I populated the map while instantiating it. The problem that I am facing is while I'm iterating through the map and try to have access to the value of each key I'm getting some errors. I believe the return value might need to be cast from variant to its real data type. I really don't know how to have access to it.

this is the definition of the map: map> mapToBeProcessed;

```
map<string,boost::variant<int,double, long long, string>> mapToBeProcessed;

for(auto &x: mapToBeProcessed)
{
  if(ini.hasField(x.first))
  {
    b << x.first << x.second;
  }
}

//
```

The issue is happening when I'm trying to access the value of the map: x.second

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that you don't know *which* of the "variants" you really have. You can look at `boost::variant` (or `std::variant`) as a fancy `union`, the compiler can't know which of the elements in the variant (union) that is the valid one, it's up to you to keep track of that.

Comment: With a variant, you typically also need to use a visitor pattern. That is, instead of you writing the logic of "if this type, then X", you create functions for *each* type, and then pass that to a `boost::visit`, which will call the correct function. Please post what your errors are. Also a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can visit the variant, to apply a function to the active member.

```
struct stream_visitor {
    using result_type = void;
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) { os << name << t; }
    std::ostream & os;
    std::string name;
}

map<string,boost::variant<int,double, long long, string>> mapToBeProcessed;

for(auto &x: mapToBeProcessed)
{
  if(ini.hasField(x.first))
  {
    boost::apply_visitor(stream_visitor{ b, x.first }, x.second);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering how would you readjust the your logic in your struct to just return the value of x.second. Rather than printing it out. template<typename T> T operator()(T& t){return t;}  ?

Comment: @Ben that doesn't work. There must be *one* return type